# Changing the color of image on hover using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

As i am having images on my web page.On hover the image color should be changed as blue for first red for second one etcc..Right now the images are in black and white on hover the color of the image should be changed.Thanks In Advance

Here is my code:

```
<div class="ourexpertise">
                    <div id="content">
                    <img src="image/expertise/1.png"  />
                    <img src="image/expertise/2.png" />
                    <img src="image/expertise/3.png" />                     
                </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/x7qrd9zr/

Comment: your fiddle does not work.

Comment: you want to work with img tag? or no problem to using div tag?

Comment: Images are not displaying but on hover that image color should be chnaged to gold or red or anyother color

Comment: @mimi Not like that to use only img tag div also we can use

Comment: aha I got what you mean . w8 a moment pls

Comment: I don't think you can do this with css, there is 2 way, first one using opacity in my opinion it doesn't work but you can test it. second one change image color in photo editor like Photoshop and then add it when hover. or using conveys html5 maybe it work

Comment: @mimi thank you i have solved by doing that

Comment: @user6704343 your welcome I didn't do anything :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating on overlay div over the image with the "background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)" for red, as an example.
However, this will only create an "illusion" of color changing. To change the color properly, you really should use the HTML5 canvas, as it involves using the blending modes.
Or, you can transform your B/W picture into a picture, where white color becomes completely transparent and black becomes completely untransparent. Use this picture as an overlay onto a div with a fixed color - change the fixed color to red or blue as soon as you need to recolour the image.